# unable to read .txt file from flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, iis, iis-7.5, flutter-web

I am trying to read a text file from flutter web.It works as expected when i run the app locally.But when i deploy the web app in IIS Server,the server throws 403 error(Forbidden).Does Flutter web(or any web app) blocks reading the text files or can i configure IIS Server to add this text file as an exception?
Please let me know if there are additional steps needed to read a file in Flutter web.

The text has been placed under assets folder and the path has been mapped to pubspec.yml file.

Below is my Flutter doctor:

```html
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.291, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1316], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-8.0.pre.291 at D:\Flutter
    • Framework revision c1042314a9 (3 months ago), 2020-11-18 01:38:02 -0500
    • Engine revision 35a0b9fe68
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-50.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Vasanth\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.150
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a Flutter-related issue, rather than a server-related issue. I would recommend looking into how to enable connections from other client to access that file. Are you using any type of authentication on the web server? Does this file have access restrictions? Theses are just a few things to look into. I am not an IIS admin so I cannot help you any more than this. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,i found a fix or may be workaround!

The problem is that,the main.dart file runs perfectly fine on hot reload for local web but the code/UI changes doesnt reflect during the release build done using "flutter build web".I dont know if its a bug or i am missing some steps.

So I created a new project,copied all the files there and copied only the contents of main.dart file to the new project's main.dart file.

After the above step,it worked as expected in the release build!